# Preventing enter key down on button - Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I only want to fire my button on click events (not on pressing enter), and it works in a dynamic way right now:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" v-on="{ click: isInProgress ? stop : start }">
```

My question is, how to put the prevent modifier to click this way?
I know deleting the `type="button"` would do the trick too, but I cannot.

So what's the `@click.prevent=""` - solution for the `v-on` way?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to stop "keydown.enter" from firing the button you can use `keydown.enter.prevent`

```
 <button
    class=""
    type="button"
    v-on:keydown.enter.prevent
    v-on="{ click: isInProgress ? stop : start }"
  ></button>
```